# Google Earth Engine: different stretch options

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I'm working on a map view that detects new ice using Sentinel-1 together with Google Earth Engine.

When adding images to Google Earth Engine I can set the min and max values for my layer in numbers but then in the map view I have the possibility to change change these values and also select different stretch options.

[image: visualization parameters]

Is it possible to choose one of these options instead of entering a max and min view in the code? Right now my code end looks like this:

```js
Map.addLayer(hh2017, {

bands: ["HH"],
max: -5,
min: -19,
opacity: 1,
palette: ['002bff','a4d5ff','979797','080358','000029' ]

}, 'sentinel-1');
```

I want it to be `Stretch: 90%` The reason I need to stretch the image each time is that they all look a bit different.

Comment: May I take this space to ask for reference in order to better understand min/max and stretch? There is a specific question about that though https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304180/what-are-the-min-and-max-values-of-map-addlayer-on-google-earth-engine.

Answer (score 6):

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization#styled-layer-descriptors), you may want to try a Styled Layer Descriptor.  The previous answer also works, but requires you to use `getInfo()`, which can cause your browser to lock (see [Client-Server doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) for details).  Here's another approach:

```js
var i = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterBounds(Map.getCenter())
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first());
Map.centerObject(i);
Map.addLayer(i);

function setDisplay(dictionary) {
  var visParams = {
    bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], 
    min: [
      dictionary['B4_p5'], dictionary['B3_p5'], dictionary['B2_p5']
    ],
    max: [
      dictionary['B4_p95'], dictionary['B3_p95'], dictionary['B2_p95']
    ]
  };
  Map.layers().set(0, ui.Map.Layer(i, visParams));
}

Map.onChangeBounds(function() {
  var params = i.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([5, 95]), 
    geometry: Map.getBounds(true), 
    scale: Map.getScale(),
  });
  params.evaluate(setDisplay);
});
```

Comment: That saves a lot of typing, very cool. You aren't winning in your crusade to banish getInfo :-)

Comment: I like this approach, mainly because it does the job in the current display as the user changes bounds, but as I see it, this solution doesn't avoid the Client-Server protocol, it just retrieves information *asynchronously* using `evaluate` whether `getInfo` does it *synchronously*. Sure in this case is better to use `evaluate`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to stretch based on statistics for a fixed region, you can use the following approach, which demonstrates both percentage and standard deviation based stretches.

```js
// Function for displaying stretched image based on standard devitations from the mean.
var AddLayerStdDevStretch = function(img, sampling_geom, num_stddev) {
  var stats = img.select(['elevation'],['value']).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().combine({reducer2:ee.Reducer.stdDev(), sharedInputs:true})
                              .setOutputs(['mean', 'stddev']), 
    geometry: sampling_geom,
    scale: 30, 
    bestEffort: true
  });
  var vis_params = ee.Dictionary({
      'min': ee.Number(stats.get('value_mean'))
               .subtract(ee.Number(num_stddev).multiply(ee.Number(stats.get('value_stddev')))),
      'max': ee.Number(stats.get('value_mean'))
               .add(ee.Number(num_stddev).multiply(ee.Number(stats.get('value_stddev')))),
    });
  Map.addLayer({
    eeObject: img,
    visParams: vis_params.getInfo(),
    name: num_stddev + ' sigma'
  });
};

// Function for displaying stretched image based on percentile values.
var AddLayerPercentStretch = function(img, sampling_geom, percent) {
  var lower_percentile = ee.Number(100).subtract(percent).divide(2);
  var upper_percentile = ee.Number(100).subtract(lower_percentile);
  var stats = img.select(['elevation'],['value']).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile({percentiles: [lower_percentile, upper_percentile]}).setOutputs(['lower', 'upper']),
    geometry: sampling_geom,
    scale: 30, 
    bestEffort: true
  });
  var vis_params = ee.Dictionary({
      'min': ee.Number(stats.get('value_lower')),
      'max': ee.Number(stats.get('value_upper'))
    });
  Map.addLayer({
    eeObject: img,
    visParams: vis_params.getInfo(),
    name: percent + '%'
  });
};

// Sample use - add layers with various stretches to the map.
var image = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-112.6, 36.3],
          [-112.6, 35.9],
          [-111.9, 35.9],
          [-111.9, 36.3]]]);
Map.centerObject(geometry);
AddLayerStdDevStretch(image, geometry, 1);
AddLayerStdDevStretch(image, geometry, 2);
AddLayerStdDevStretch(image, geometry, 3);
AddLayerPercentStretch(image, geometry, 90);
AddLayerPercentStretch(image, geometry, 98);
AddLayerPercentStretch(image, geometry, 100);
Map.addLayer(geometry, {}, 'geometry used for stretch statistics');
```

Note that the percentage based stretches are based on a histogram (see [ee.Reducer.percentile](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eereducerpercentile)), so the 100% stretch may not exactly match the extreme values within the sampling region.

Comment: Tyler, your answer is great. However, It works for single band raster only. How can I achieve 3 standard deviation stretch for a 3-band raster?

Answer (score 4):

For stretching using the mean and standard deviation I wrote a function available in https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools. I do not know how GEE does it when you do it as you mention (developers like as Noel Gorelick may know), but somehow it has slightly different values, see the test.

```js
var stretch_std = function(n_std) {
  var mean = i.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: i.geometry(),
    bestEffort: true})
  var std = i.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
    geometry: i.geometry(),
    bestEffort: true})
  var min = mean.map(function(key, val){
      return ee.Number(val).subtract(ee.Number(std.get(key)).multiply(n_std))
    }).getInfo()
  var max = mean.map(function(key, val){
      return ee.Number(val).add(ee.Number(std.get(key)).multiply(n_std))
    }).getInfo()

  return {vmin: min, vmax: max}
}

// TEST
var i = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA_FMASK/LC82310902013296LGN00")
var s = stretch_std(3)
var min = ee.Number(ee.List([s.vmin.B5, s.vmin.B6, s.vmin.B4]).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()))
var max = ee.Number(ee.List([s.vmax.B5, s.vmax.B6, s.vmax.B4]).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()))
var viz = {bands:["B5", "B6", "B4"],
           min: min.getInfo(),
           max: max.getInfo()}
var vizEE = {bands:["B5", "B6", "B4"],
           min: -0.06102305441591904,
           max: 0.41922686174360246}
print(viz)
Map.centerObject(i)
Map.addLayer(i, {bands:["B5", "B6", "B4"],
                 min:0, max:1}, "not streched")
Map.addLayer(i, vizEE, "streched by EE")
Map.addLayer(i, viz, "streched by gee_tools")
```